# Why is there a difference between coroutine builders for CompletableFuture and ListenableFuture?

Tags: kotlin, guava, java.util.concurrent, coroutine, kotlin-coroutines

While examining source of Kotlin coroutines, I noticed a difference (marked with `**`) between [JDK 8 CompletableFuture](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-jdk8/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/future/Future.kt)

```
public fun <T> future(
    context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): CompletableFuture<T> {
    require(!start.isLazy) { "$start start is not supported" }
    val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
    val job = Job(newContext[Job])
    val future = CompletableFutureCoroutine<T>(newContext + job)
    job.cancelFutureOnCompletion(future)
    ** future.whenComplete { _, exception -> job.cancel(exception) } **
    start(block, receiver=future, completion=future) // use the specified start strategy
    return future
}


private class CompletableFutureCoroutine<T>(
    override val context: CoroutineContext
) : CompletableFuture<T>(), Continuation<T>, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext get() = context
    override val isActive: Boolean get() = context[Job]!!.isActive
    override fun resume(value: T) { complete(value) }
    override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) { completeExceptionally(exception) }
    ** doesn't override cancel which corresponds to interrupt task **
}
```

and [Guava ListenableFuture](https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/integration/kotlinx-coroutines-guava/src/main/kotlin/kotlinx/coroutines/experimental/guava/ListenableFuture.kt)

```
public fun <T> future(
    context: CoroutineContext = DefaultDispatcher,
    start: CoroutineStart = CoroutineStart.DEFAULT,
    block: suspend CoroutineScope.() -> T
): ListenableFuture<T> {
    require(!start.isLazy) { "$start start is not supported" }
    val newContext = newCoroutineContext(context)
    val job = Job(newContext[Job])
    val future = ListenableFutureCoroutine<T>(newContext + job)
    job.cancelFutureOnCompletion(future)
    start(block, receiver=future, completion=future) // use the specified start strategy
    return future
}

private class ListenableFutureCoroutine<T>(
    override val context: CoroutineContext
) : AbstractFuture<T>(), Continuation<T>, CoroutineScope {
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext get() = context
    override val isActive: Boolean get() = context[Job]!!.isActive
    override fun resume(value: T) { set(value) }
    override fun resumeWithException(exception: Throwable) { setException(exception) }
    ** override fun interruptTask() { context[Job]!!.cancel() } **
}
```

integrations, though I think of the types as nearly equivalent (except of course `ListenableFuture` can't be completed directly, but I don't see why this matters here). Is there a specific reason behind this difference?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [CompletableFuture.cancel](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/CompletableFuture.html#cancel-boolean-) is an open (overridable) method, but it is not *designed for override*. Its documentation does not provide any guarantee for its invocation on cancellation, so the only future-proof (pun intended) way to learn that `CompletableFuture` was cancelled is by installing `whenComplete` listener on it.

For example, it is perfectly legal for a future version of JDK to add yet another method to cancel a future that does not internally invoke `cancel`. Such a change would not violate any piece of `CompletableFuture` contract.

Compare this with documentation on [AbstractFuture.interruptTask](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/19.0/api/docs/com/google/common/util/concurrent/AbstractFuture.html#interruptTask()). This method is explicitly designed for override and its documentation guarantees conditions under which it is invoked. Thus, we can provide a slightly more efficient implementation for `ListenableFuture` builder that avoids creation of lambda to install a cancellation listener on it.